# How to remove a class from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a piece of JavaScript code that validates a form. If the input field is empty I'm adding the "empty" which puts a red background on the input field.

Is there a way to remove that class when the user clicks on the field?

I had tried this, but it did not work.

```
  $('input').bind('blur', function(){        
      $(this).removeClass('empty');
     });
```

```js
    function register()
    {
     var errornotice = "This field is required"; 
     
     if(document.myForma.userid.value == '')
     {
      var id = $("#userid"); 
      id.addClass("empty");
      id.val(errornotice); 
     } 
     
     if(document.myForma.fullname.value == '')
     {
      var name = $("#fullname"); 
      name.addClass("empty");
      name.val(errornotice);
       
     }
     
     if($(":input").hasClass("empty"))
     {
      return false;
     }
     else
     {
      errornotice.hide();
      return true;
     } 
     
     
     $('input').bind('blur', function(){  
       $(this).removeClass('empty');
      });  
    }
```

```css
.empty
    {
     background:red;
     color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="index.php" method="post" id="apply-form input" onSubmit="return(register());" name="myForma">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userN">User Name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" id="userid"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">Full name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control">
        <p id="empty"></p>
      </div> 
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Why not using  `$('input').click(....)` ?

Comment: 1) Don't add event handlers to elements within other event handlers; move the event handler binding somewhere else. 2) `bind()` had been deprecated in jQuery for a long time. Unless you have to use an old version of jQuery, use `on()`. 3) Blur is the event which occurs when a user leaves a field, not when they enter the field. Try `focusin`.

Comment: You need to add the event handler *before* the `return`. Code after a return statement is never executed.

Comment: if by 'click' you mean when the field receives context use the _focus_ event, not _blur_ (which occurs only when focus is lost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were on the right track by using on blur, but I would recommend using on focus and also change the text to the empty string. Also, the way it looks like you want your text to behave is more like a [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp), so you may want to consider using that, but the code below doesn't use it.

```js
    function register()
    {
     var errornotice = "This field is required"; 
     
     if(document.myForma.userid.value == '')
     {
      var id = $("#userid"); 
      id.addClass("empty");
      id.val(errornotice); 
     } 
     
     if(document.myForma.fullname.value == '')
     {
      var name = $("#fullname"); 
      name.addClass("empty");
      name.val(errornotice);
       
     }
     
     $('.form-control').bind('focus', function(){ 
          $(this).val('');
       $(this).removeClass('empty');
      });  
    }
```

```css
.empty
    {
     background:red;
     color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="index.php" method="post" id="apply-form input" onSubmit="return(register());" name="myForma">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userN">User Name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" id="userid"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">Full name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control">
        <p id="empty"></p>
      </div> 
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function register()
    {
     var errornotice = "This field is required"; 
     
     if(document.myForma.userid.value == '')
     {
      var id = $("#userid"); 
      id.addClass("empty");
      id.val(errornotice); 
     } 
     
     if(document.myForma.fullname.value == '')
     {
      var name = $("#fullname"); 
      name.addClass("empty");
      name.val(errornotice);
       
     }
     
     if($(":input").hasClass("empty"))
     {
      return false;
     }
     else
     {
      errornotice.hide();
      return true;
     } 
    }     
     
    $('input[type="text"]').bind('focus', function(){  
     $(this).removeClass('empty').val('');
    });
```

```css
.empty
    {
     background:red;
     color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="index.php" method="post" id="apply-form input" onSubmit="return(register());" name="myForma">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userN">User Name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" id="userid"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">Full name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control">
        <p id="empty"></p>
      </div> 
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the focus() method to remove the class when the user clicks on this control. This will work with a mouse and a keyboard as well.

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){       
    $(this).removeClass('empty').val('');
});
```

```js
function register()
    {
     var errornotice = "This field is required"; 
     
     if(document.myForma.userid.value == '')
     {
      var id = $("#userid"); 
      id.addClass("empty");
      id.val(errornotice); 
     } 
     
     if(document.myForma.fullname.value == '')
     {
      var name = $("#fullname"); 
      name.addClass("empty");
      name.val(errornotice);
       
     }
     
     if($(":input").hasClass("empty"))
     {
      return false;
     }
     else
     {
      errornotice.hide();
      return true;
     } 
    }     
     
    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){  
     $(this).removeClass('empty').val('');
    });
```

```css
.empty
    {
     background:red;
     color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="index.php" method="post" id="apply-form input" onSubmit="return(register());" name="myForma">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userN">User Name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" id="userid"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">Full name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control">
        <p id="empty"></p>
      </div> 
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"> 
    </form>
```